# Android: Is it smarter to make 2 RecyclerViews or 2 Adapters?

Tags: java, android, adapter, android-recyclerview

I have a program I am writing where I have 2 tabs, when one is clicked, the recyclerview on the page updates with information X (Name, email, etc). When they click on the second tab it updates with information Y (phone, password, etc).

Is it better resource management / smarter to create 2 separate recyclerviews / adapters and change which is active? Or is it better to use 1 recyclerview with 2 adapters that adjust themselves dynamically?

My goal is to make it effective, manage resources efficiently, and also be able to change between the two very quickly.

-Pat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a `Fragment` for each tab (could be the same class). Don't worry about the resources, recyclerviews are highly optimized.

For me its the more logical approach and it's easier to understand, especially for others if you're working in a team. Also you could change the view much easier and more dynamic in future, for example in a tablet/large screen view.

greets

Comment: Very clearly explained, thank you. I shall do that. One follow-up question, if I am already within a fragment and will therefore be making a sub-fragment as a result, will that change this at all? Or would your answer stay the same?

Comment: You're welcome! I would use (Nested) Fragments cause it's more elegant. But honestly, I don't have much experience in nested fragments :)

Comment: The Android Support Library also now supports nested fragments, so you can implement nested fragment designs on Android 1.6 and higher.